# Hibernate Validator on Weblogic 10

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jpa, weblogic

I came across error when deploying application using Hibernate Validator on Weblogic 10 server.

When application runs form validation via annotations it crashes with error:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.(InterpolationTerm.java:60)
            at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
            at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
            at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:120)
```

This error does not occur when application run on Tomcat server.

We have weblogic-web-app file set as:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

All libs are depolyed with app.

Validation libs:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Sample validation:

```
 @NotEmpty(message = "{newQuote.source}")
```

We tried to set preffered packages in weblogic.xml, removed JPA lib from weblogic modules both without effect.

It looks like some problem with loading properties file for validation messages but what can be reason of it ?

Answer (score 2):

I realize the post is bit old and probably resolved. Just wanted to updated anyway if someone else encounter the same issue.

The underlying problem is multiple jar resolution/conflict. Weblogic references and loaded the EL classes from the system provided jars listed below (located in the modules directory)

1. glassfish.el_*.jar
2. javax.jsp_1*.jar

In my case I need to instruct weblogic server to load classes of the below listed packages from the jar located within the application (weblogic-application.xml in ear)

```
  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.el.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.el.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
```

one can provide the same configuration in weblogic.xml if it's just web-app.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm

Comment: yep, that was the problem.